# Create a pdf from a React Native Form and send it to a cloud storage with an Expo APP

Tags: react-native, expo

I search a way to convert my React Native Form to a pdf and then send it automatically to a Cloud Storage.
The user process :

1 - Fill a form
2 - Submit the form

Hidden Process from user
3 - Create a pdf from the form datas
4 - Store it to a cloud Storage

I updated my question, with more details.
For example I have a form in my APP, and I want at the end, a pdf file button to create the PDF with the value from the user and send it to a server to save it on the cloud.

Here is my form

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import BouncyCheckbox from "react-native-bouncy-checkbox";

import {
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";
// Galio components
import { Block, Text, Button as GaButton, theme } from "galio- 
framework";
// Argon themed components
import { argonTheme, tabs, articles } from "../constants/";
import {  Input, Button, View, Card, Select, Icon, Header, 
Switch } from "../components/";

const { width } = Dimensions.get("screen");

class Tall extends React.Component {
state = {
 "switch-1": true,
 "switch-2": false
};

 renderText = () => {
  return (
   <Block flex style={styles.group}>
     <Text size={22} style={styles.title}>
       1 - HEIGHT
     </Text>
     <Block style={{ paddingHorizontal: theme.SIZES.BASE }}>
       <Text size={18}
         h3
         style={{ fontFamily: 'open-sans-regular', 
  marginBottom: theme.SIZES.BASE / 1 }}
        color={argonTheme.COLORS.DEFAULT}
      >
   - ARE YOU TALL ?
      </Text>
     </Block>
   </Block>
  );
  };

 renderSwitches = () => {
  return (
    <Block flex style={styles.group}>

    <Block style={{ paddingHorizontal: theme.SIZES.BASE }}>
      <Block
        row
        middle
        space="between"
        style={{ marginBottom: theme.SIZES.BASE }}
      >
         <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'open-sans-regular' }} size={14} color={argonTheme.COLORS.TEXT}>YES</Text>

        <BouncyCheckbox
          size={25}
          fillColor="green"
          unfillColor="#FFFFFF"

          iconStyle={{ borderColor: "green" }}
          onPress={(isChecked: boolean) => {}}
        />

      </Block>
      <Block row middle space="between">
        <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'open-sans-regular' }} size={14} color={argonTheme.COLORS.TEXT}>NO</Text>
        <BouncyCheckbox
          size={25}
          fillColor="red"
          unfillColor="#FFFFFF"

          iconStyle={{ borderColor: "red" }}
          onPress={(isChecked: boolean) => {}}
        />
       </Block>
      </Block>
      </Block>
    );
  };

  
  renderButtons = () => {
   return (
    <Block flex>

       <Block center>
         <Button textStyle={{ fontFamily: 'open-sans-bold' }} color="success" style={styles.button}>
         SEND
         </Button>
         </Block>


     </Block>
   );
  };

 render() {
   return (
    <Block flex center>
    <ScrollView
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 30, width }}
    >
      {this.renderText()}
      {this.renderSwitches()}
        {this.renderButtons()}


      </ScrollView>
    </Block>
   );
  }
  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
title: {
fontFamily: 'open-sans-bold',
paddingBottom: theme.SIZES.BASE,
paddingHorizontal: theme.SIZES.BASE * 2,
marginTop: 44,
color: argonTheme.COLORS.HEADER
 },
 group: {
paddingTop: theme.SIZES.BASE * 2
 },
shadow: {
shadowColor: "black",
shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
shadowRadius: 4,
shadowOpacity: 0.2,
elevation: 2
},
button: {
marginBottom: 40,
marginTop: 80,
width: width - theme.SIZES.BASE * 2
},
optionsButton: {
width: "auto",
height: 34,
paddingHorizontal: theme.SIZES.BASE,
paddingVertical: 10
},
input: {
borderBottomWidth: 1
},
inputDefault: {
borderBottomColor: argonTheme.COLORS.PLACEHOLDER
},
inputTheme: {
borderBottomColor: argonTheme.COLORS.PRIMARY
},
inputTheme: {
borderBottomColor: argonTheme.COLORS.PRIMARY
},
inputInfo: {
borderBottomColor: argonTheme.COLORS.INFO
},
inputSuccess: {
borderBottomColor: argonTheme.COLORS.SUCCESS
},


});

export default Tall;
```

How I use Expo PRINT to retrieve the user choice (Are you tall ? Yes or NO) in the const HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with expo Print

```
const user = {
  name: 'Foub',
  surname: 'Bouf'
};
const html = `<div style="color: red">Mr.${user.name} ${user.surname}</div>`;
const { base64 } = await Print.printToFileAsync({
  html
});
// send the base64 which is a string containing the pdf's data to the server
```

You can put whatever HTML you want with whatever style you want, like a real HTML page

Comment: Thank you. I implement Expo Print and it works. But I can't find out how to add dynamically the user form data in the const html.

Comment: I updated my answer to put user.name and user.surname, to show you how you can put data inside of your pdf, you can style your HTML page that you want in your pdf

Comment: I also added a style to show you have you can add styles

Comment: I edit my question for more details !

Comment: You don't have any inputs in your component, you have to have inputs, and when you press the send button, you get those input's values, and you put them in an HTML like I showed you

Comment: I created an example in snack, try running it, on your phone: https://snack.expo.dev/@abdallahmeddah/stackoverflowpdf

Comment: Thank you for your help. I manage to install your snack example on my project, but I can't find out how to use my checkbox button as an Input. I mean when my user check the checkbox YES, the value of this checkbox automatically goes to the pdf print. I don't want users to write themselves the answer YES or NO. I hope my explaination is enough clear :)